# How can I make ctrlp do better filename matching?

Tags: filesystem, plugin-ctrlp

My project has these files:

```
$ find . -type f -and -name 'peop*'
./app/assets/stylesheets/admin/sections/people.css.sass
./app/controllers/admin/people_controller.rb
```

As I got tired of typing `:e app/assets/stylesheets/admin/sections/people.css.sass`, I thought that [ctrlp](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) might be a good way to save some typing. However, I can't get it to match files in what I consider to be a sane way.

First, I use `<C-p>` and type `peop`, and that gives me these results ("first" match is at the bottom):

```
> app/models/attribute_group.rb
> app/models/contract_template.rb
> app/policies/contract_policy.rb
> app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb
> app/policies/invoice_policy.rb
> app/views/layouts/pdf.pdf.haml
> app/uploaders/logo_uploader.rb
> app/models/property_object.rb
> app/policies/person_policy.rb
> app/policies/photo_policy.rb    
>>> peop_
```

These results are horrible. Neither files with `peop` in them are there. Even when I expand it to `people`:

```
> app/policies/contract_template_policy.rb
> app/models/concerns/exportable.rb
> app/models/contract_template.rb
> app/uploaders/photo_uploader.rb
> app/uploaders/logo_uploader.rb
> app/views/admin/people/_show.html.haml
> app/views/admin/people/_form.html.haml
> app/views/admin/people/show.html.haml
> app/views/admin/people/edit.html.haml
> app/views/admin/people/new.html.haml 
>>> people_
```

It doesn't list either of them (!)

I went through `:help ctrlp-options`, and found a single option that improves things somewhat:

```
Set this to 1 to set searching by filename (as opposed to full path) as the
default:
  let g:ctrlp_by_filename = 0

Can be toggled on/off by pressing <c-d> inside the prompt.
```

After setting this, I get the following results on `peop`:

```
> app/controllers/admin/organisation_people_controller.rb
> app/assets/stylesheets/admin/sections/people.css.sass
> doc/formulieren/opdrachtverlening-woningbeheer.pdf
> doc/formulieren/hulptabellen-object-unit-soort.pdf
> doc/formulieren/brandpreventievoorjongeren.pdf
> app/policies/organisation_person_policy.rb
> doc/prototype-admin/prototype/inspectiemodule_apparaten.html
> app/policies/property_object_policy.rb
> app/policies/person_policy.rb
> app/controllers/admin/people_controller.rb
>d> peop_
```

Okay, so this is slightly better, I get at least one of the expected files at the first result, and the other one as the 9th. It still conciders `hulptabellen-object-unit-soort.pdf` to be a better match than `people.css.sass` though (!)

Typing `people` finally gives me the 2 expected files as the first 2:

```
> app/controllers/admin/organisation_people_controller.rb
> app/assets/stylesheets/admin/sections/people.css.sass
> app/controllers/admin/people_controller.rb
>>> people_
```

How can I make this matching better? I don't mind "fuzzy matching", but it should not be so fuzzy it matches everything and everyone... In this case, I would expect typing `<c-P>peop` to have `app/assets/stylesheets/admin/sections/people.css.sass` as either the 1st or 2nd match.

Comment: It appears that ctrlp can accept a custom matching function.  It is in the documentation under `'g:ctrlp_match_func`  A good example of this in use is this plugin: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4884

Answer (score 7):

A similar question was just asked on the Vim reddit [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/2yg5ss/has_your_ctrlp_gotten_slow_change_the_indexer_and/). I started using [ctrlp-cmatcher](https://github.com/JazzCore/ctrlp-cmatcher/)  myself quite awhile ago which I find to be much more intelligent at matching the right file. Note that it does require a compiled component. Otherwise you'll have to try some of the approaches in the [article](http://blog.patspam.com/2014/super-fast-ctrlp).

Answer (score 4):

CtrlP has a few different modes, `Ctrl-R` and `Ctrl-D`. `Ctrl-R` uses your input as raw Regex, meaning you'll only find matches with `people` in it explicitly. `Ctrl-D` matches only the filename, ignoring the path.

I believe the default CtrlP functionality is just joining `.*` to every character as a raw character, so a period is treated as a period. If you knew in advance the file was at least 2 directories deep, you could do `//people`.